# How to ensure UTF-8 encoding of source code in JGit commits

Tags: git, utf-8, jgit

I have some automated GIT commit in my project. I achieve commits therein using `org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand`. But the source files are getting committed with a few garbled characters. I suspect the commits are not being done with the source files in **UTF-8** format.
How do I specify this?

Comment: You have to set the correct encoding in you editor. Git itself has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Do you write and read files in Java, too? Could you show that part of code?

Comment: No @MincongHuang , I only commit them. The files are being altered in some other tool in turn. Probably, the encoding needs to be fixed there. Isn't it!!